# Call method from alertdialog onclicklistener (in fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am stuck in seemingly simple thing but couldn't find a way. I have a method and an alertdialog inside a fragment. I want to call that method from alertdialog's onclickListener.

The issue is, the method is not recognizable from in side on click listener. Do I need to use separate DialogFragment and interface? Is there any straight forward way without creating an extra class?

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {
    public void samplefile(){
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        myDialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");
        String[] filetypelist = {"A","B","C"};
        myDialog.setItems(filetypelist, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ((SettingsFragment) getActivity()).dloadSample(which);
            }
        }); 
        myDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        myDialog.create().show();
    }

    public void dloadSample(int args) {
        //SOMETHING TO DO HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your method:

```
getActivity()
    .getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, new nameOfYourFragmentToBeCalled())
    .commit();`
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess my subject was little misleading. I don't want to call a new fragment. I need to call a method in the same fragment that the dialog is in.

Comment: Make that method as static